# I'm using a function to delete all the names in vba but I have an error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, range

I got this piece of code from https://www.extendoffice.com/

```
Sub DeleteNames()
'Update 20140314
Dim xName As Name
For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    xName.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

But when I try to run it give me an error 1004 (syntax of this name is incorrect) on the line `xName.Delete`

Comment: Guessing a bit here, but likely there is a named range in your workbook that has a bad formula in it, so instead of just deleting the named range it's throwing an error. Again, that's a guess. Naively, I might try setting the name to a known range before deleting and see if that clears it up, like `xname.RefersTo = "=Sheet1!A1"` (just before the `delete` line). Probably best to back this workbook up though before running this type of code as it's pretty heavy handed stuff.

Comment: So, it didn't work, and now I have the error on the line `xName.RefersTo = "=data!A1"` data is the name of the sheet I'm working with

Comment: You might need to hunt through your named ranges in the front-end and see if you can find which one is causing the issue. (Unless someone else pops up in here with a better idea, of course).

Comment: Does the name of that Name (I know, sounds strange...) starts with `_xlfn`? Thats an internal name that you can't access or delete.

Comment: the thing is that it works perfectly fine without removing them, but it could happen that they are a lot that could be created if I don't remove them

Comment: I don't know `_xlfn` is so I guess it is not

Comment: I mean maybe, as in the sub it goes through all the Names. Maybe I should try to detect if there is some of these name that the program is trying to delete as well

Comment: Okay so I just checked with `MsgBox xName.Name` and there are indeed some Name ranges starting with `_xlfn`. I'll try using an if and a Split to separate them.

Comment: thanks for the help, it was exactly that. And I made a fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that it try to delete "hidden" internal Name ranges that start with a `_xlfn` which I cannot remove. so I use a Split to check if it starts with `_xlfn` and if it don't, then it means I can delete it.

```
Sub DeleteNames()
    Dim xName As Name
    For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If Split(xName.Name, ".")(0) <> "_xlfn" Then
            xName.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from internal Names that are issued from Excel and start with an underscore. As far as I know, all those names start with `_xlfn`. They are a hint that an Excel file was created with a newer version of Excel and then opened with an older version that doesn't support some features (eg functions in a formula), see for example [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/named-ranges-with-xlfn-prefixes/m-p/3568641)

Those Names cannot be deleted. I guess the error message is a little misleading, it would be better if there would be a message like *"this object cannot be deleted."*. Anyhow, the workaround is easy, either check the name of that Name or enclose the
deletion with an error handler:

```
For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    if left(xName.Name, 1) <> "_" Then xName.Delete
Next
```

Or

```
For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    On Error Resume Next
    xName.Delete
    On Error Goto 0
Next
```